# Laravel/Eloquent: How to use WHERE LIKE for combined fields?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've a form with **1 input** to **filter by the full(!) name**:

```
<label>Search by fullname:</label>
<input type="text" name="fullname">
```

**Problem**: the fullname is splitted into **3 fields** in my databases **user table**:

## users

| id | title | firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dr. | John | Doe |
| 2 |  | Peter | Pan |

`fullname = title + firstname + lastname`

I'd like to **find results** for inputs **like** *Dr. Doe*, but also *John Doe* or just *Peter*.

Currently I only know how to filter each field separately:

```
$users = User::where('firstname', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')->get();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [DB::raw()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions) and [MySQL's concat](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp) to achieve this:

```
$users = User::where(DB::raw('concat(title," ",firstname," ",lastname)'), 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a full-text index of `title`, `firstname` and `lastname` fields in the `user` table is a more correct approach to go.

You can perform a `DB::raw` query using `MATCH(...columns) AGAINST expr` syntax. <sup>[1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match)</sup>

The cost of this approach is that the index is updated on writes.
However, this gives you a robust search without you having to care about the ordering of any of the fields in the search query.

Answer (score 1):

Like Davit's answer, not a **best solution**, but it'll probably work.

```php
$fullName = "Mr Philip Phil Philips";

$nameParts = explode(' ', $fullName);

$matching_users = User::whereIn('first_name', $nameParts)
                        ->orWhereIn('last_name', $nameParts)
                        ->orWhereIn('title', $nameparts)
                        ->get();
```